# Why Spring Custom Login Form not found but other pages works fine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying out add Custom Login Page in Sprint Security but it ends up with page not found error 404. I've already have implemented login mechanism and it works for default Spring Security login form. Now I don't have any idea what to do to make Custom Login Page work.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.krzychu</groupId>
    <artifactId>hairdresser</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hairdresser</name>
    <description>Haidresser CRUD</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.krzychu.hairdresser.config;

import com.krzychu.hairdresser.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

login.html

```
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="layout :: head(title=~{::title},links=~{})">
    <title>Please Login</title>
</head>
<body th:include="layout :: body" th:with="content=~{::content}">
<div th:fragment="content">
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Please Login</legend>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Folder Structure]

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Comment: Can you share your whole Config class ?

Comment: Sure, just edited post

Answer (score 0):

You can replace EnableWebMvc with EnableWebSecurity as following

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  // ...
}
```

**Edit**
Add a Controller for login as following

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        
        // ...
        
        return "login";
    }
}
```

This example assumes you have `login.html` file in your `templates` folder

**Edit 2**
If not done yet, you must add a `ViewResolver` as a `@Bean` in your Config class

```
@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver, SpringSecurityDialect sec) {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.addDialect(sec);
    return templateEngine;
}
```

Add this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you must provide additional content. Share your `LoginController`

Comment: I dont't have LoginController. I thought I don't need it, do I?

Comment: This is exactly why the default login page was displayed. Of course, you need a Controller for this

Comment: Yeah I see. I've done that but I'm getting some 500 error hope i can figure it out. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause

Comment: I've added that but now I've got this error:

[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "login": Error resolving template [layout], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "login" - line 3, col 7)

Comment: Bro what is really your problem ? Add a `login.html` file in your `resources/templates` folder

Comment: I've got this in templates folder

Comment: `resources/templates/login.html` ? Are you sure there is not misspell ?

Comment: do you have defined the layout.html?? now it is complaining about the inserts that you have invoking layout.html.

Comment: Just added folder structure picture. No, I had not defined layout.html

Comment: Also share the `application.properties` content. Be careful, if there is `database` connection info, first remove it before posting

Comment: Added `application.properties`

Comment: Remove these lines  `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/`, `spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html` in your `application.properties`

Comment: @dm_tr Still same problem.

Comment: @dm_tr Well, I'm for sure, but even after adding that dependency  it still does't work

Comment: Lol, so am sorry bro but for the moment I dont think I can help. Maybe later if not solved. Stay strong, programmer has no life, lol

Comment: I can't help myself too I think. Thank you for wasting your time on me.

Answer (score 0):

why do not give a chance to remove the tags that have th:include="layout , just to test that the wiring of elements were done correctly, and the only part missing is the definition of the layout??